# Как закрыть приложение во время его создания?

Tags: delphi, файлы, vcl

Проверяю при загрузке программы на существование файла.
Но не могу понять как сделать так чтобы если нет файла программа закрывалась.
А если есть продолжала работу.
Сделал так но программа и так и так закрываться подскажи что не так.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  fileName: string;
begin
    fileName := 'D:\rec\Project2.dll';

    if FileExists(fileName) then
      ShowMessage(fileName+' prodolgit!')
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage(fileName+' file ne najden prog zakroetsja!');
      Form1.Close;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Close на Create вообще непонятно как сработает. Таких конструкций лучше избегать.

Comment: ExitProcess(0); смотри также: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384498/end-program-delphi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совсем по-жесткому можно сделать вот так:

```
else
begin
  ShowMessage(fileName+' file ne najden prog zakroetsja!');
  Halt;
end;
```

Comment: Лучше до создания форм сделать проверки. И если они не пройдут, то выйти и не создавать формы совсем.

Answer (score 7):

Сделайте эту проверку в DPR файле.
В самом начале программы после первого begin в DPR.
До создания форм и инициализации приложения

```
if not FileExists(FileName) then
  exit;

Application.Initialize;
```

Comment: Возможно стоит уточнить, для начинающих, в каком месте стоит добавлять эту проверку. Т.е. привести более полный фрагмент DPR файла с такой проверкой.

Comment: В самое начало программы после первого begin в dpr. До создания форм и инициализации приложения.

Comment: А в dpr можно писать `exit;`? Не знал.

Comment: Конечно можно:) А потом после последней строчки кода в dpr начинается finalization юнитов.